# How to create and use Custom hooks

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

I am newbie in wordpress. I have just created contact us plugin for my own project.

In my plugin I have used many functions you can take a [look of my code.](http://pastebin.com/BXbBTEpS)

I want to make this plugin based on custom hooks instead of only PHP functions. I don't want simple plain php functions.

Can you suggest me where can I add custom hooks and how to use it?

I know how to add custom hooks and use it i have referred [this document](http://sandbox.ronggur.com/2011/08/09/wordpress-custom-action-hook-in-action/).. so I am clear with hooks (how to create it and use it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to put hooks will depend on each project. However, some *basic places* to think about:

- Shortcodes
- Querying posts
- Extending markup

I would recommend the article [Writing Extensible Plugins With Actions and Filters](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/writing-extensible-plugins-with-actions-and-filters/). It may help you to expand your ideas.

Comment: Glad to help. If I answered your question, don't forget to accept the answer :-)